# How to improve a singly linked list insert function - C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, singly-linked-list

I'm making a dictionary using a singly linked list with a recursive insert function which currently does it's job. 
I have two requests from the community:

1. I'm wondering if someone can review my code and tell me if there are any memory leaks and if so how should I remove them.
2. From looking at other lists I see they all use a tail node. Why is this necessary?

```
void dictionary::insert(Key k, Item i)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node(k, i);
    }
    else insertRec(k, i, head);
}
void dictionary::insertRec(Key k, Item i, Node* current)
{
    Node* temp;

    if (current->key == k)
    {
        current->item = i;
    }

    else if(current->nextNode != nullptr)
    {
        insertRec(k, i, current->nextNode);
    }
    else if (current->nextNode == nullptr) {

        temp = new Node(k, i);
        current->nextNode = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably this is better suit to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: 1: Maybe, or maybe not. 2: It can help if you need quick access to the tail. And this really is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but then remember to post the `Node` structure as well, including the constructor you use. Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: usually a `list` do not compare it's content, so have a tail and insert at that position is pretty reasonable approach.

Comment: Ah I didn't know this existed. Thank you. In this example how would you add the tail node?

Comment: well, a `list` usually do not have concept `key`, since you have one, have a tail would not help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't see any memory leaks in the code you posted here. There might be some elsewhere (typically in your destructor or copy constructor / assignment operator). And I don't understand why you'd implement a dictionary as a linked list. That seems rather inefficient.
2. A pointer to the last node in the list is not necessary. It doesn't buy you anything in this case because you're iterating over the whole list anyway (to find a matching key). If you don't do that, but you still want to efficiently insert at the end of the list, then a tail pointer makes sense.

However, your code can be simplified a lot:

```
void dictionary::insert(Key k, Item i)
{
    for (Node **pp = &head; *pp; pp = &(*pp)->nextNode) {
        if ((*pp)->key == k) {
            (*pp)->item = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    *pp = new Node(k, i);
}
```

It's a simple loop, no recursion required, and you don't need two separate tests for a null pointer.

---

Alternatively, if you must use recursion:

```
void dictionary::insert(Key k, Item i)
{
    insertRec(head, k, i);
}

void dictionary::insertRec(Node *&current, k, i)
{
    if (!current) {
        current = new Node(k, i);
    } else if (current->key == k) {
        current->item = i;
    } else {
        insertRec(current->nextNode, k, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The tail is a pointer to the last node in the list. The reason why I'm using a singly linked list is because it is a university assignment. We've previously done a binary search tree and I think the aim if this task is to discuss efficiency. We are also told to use explicit recursion which I nor google know what it means.